# Does entrance pupil diameter change with object distance?

Tags: optics, lenses

Here is my current understanding of things, correct me if I'm wrong.

Entrance pupil diameter effectively determines the light-gathering ability of a lens. It is related to the working f-number by the following equation:

$d = \frac{f}{N_w}$

Working f-number is, in turn, related to magnification and the "ordinary" f-number:

$N_w = (1+\frac{m}{P}) N$

Magnification drops with distance:

$m = \frac{f}{d_o-f}$

This means that $N_w$ drops with distance (asymptotically approaches $N$), which also means entrance pupil diameter enlarges with distance (asymptotically approaches $f/N$).

Is this correct? Does the entrance pupil become smaller as the object gets closer to the lens?

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong?

Comment: @sammy Because optics is not my area of expertise and I'm trying to connect the dots from various small internet sources. This is a strange property I seem to have stumbled upon in one of my calculations, that I haven't heard before.

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/stop.html#c6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Entrance and exit pupils are images which only depend on the properties of the lens. If the lens doesn't change, the pupils don't change.

The first equation is wrong. F-number is the ratio of focal length and entrance pupil diameter. It doesn't change depending on object position.

$N = \frac{f}{d}$

Working f-number $N_w$ is not involved in that ratio.